# how to use @googlemaps/js-api-loader in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I wanna use Google Maps API in React.

I read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/loading-google-maps-platform-javascript-modern-web-applications) and found out that some packages were released recently.

But I don't know even if I look at the example.

How can I use Google Maps in React?
I want to take a marker, change the marker icon.

Please help me...

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question is too vague. What have you tried? What didn't work? You need to provide a [mcve] and provide details about what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out this package and its documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

I've used it to create a google map inside a React functional component.

There are other react google map packages out there as well.

Comment: thanks a lot! I need to try this package.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely understand that there are packages that help you load Google Map and the Javascript API, e.g.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

I used `google-map-react` before, but now I need a more flexible way to load the Google Maps JavaScript API script.

For those like me who got here by searching for how to use `@googlemaps/js-api-loader` in React, here is some code sample.

1. install the npm package:
   `npm i @googlemaps/js-api-loader`
2. code sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
    version: "weekly",
    libraries: ["places"]
});

export default class DemoComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        const defaultMapOptions = {
            center: {
                lat: 40.762312,
                lng: -73.979345
            },
            zoom: 11
        };
        loader.load().then((google) => {
            const map = new google.maps.Map(
                self.googleMapDiv,
                defaultMapOptions);
            /*
                store them in the state so you can use it later
                E.g. call a function on the map object:
                    this.state.map.panTo(...)
                E.g. create a new marker:
                    new this.state.google.maps.Marker(...)
            */
            this.setState({
                google: google,
                map: map
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                ref={(ref) => { this.googleMapDiv = ref }}
                style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```